# Deleting Multiple Rows From php mysql database and file system using checbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been reading through multiple solutions to this problem and have put together my own. The only issue I run into is that it is not deleting from the file system or database.

Here are snippets of what I have:

```
$jobs = DB::ex($q);

 if ($jobs[0]['job_id']) {

 echo '<table width="100%" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6" style="font-size:9px;">';
 if ($user->properties['user_level'] == 1) {

    echo '<tr valign="middle"><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('. $jobs[$i]['job_id'] .')" /></td></tr>'; 

 }
 =======================================
 function deleteRow(jid) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete these record?")) {
        alert(jid);
        window.location = '<? echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>&delete=' + jid;
    }
  }
 ========================================================

if ($_GET['delete'] && (int)$_GET['delete'] > 0) {

    $_jid = (int)$_GET[delete];     


    foreach($_jid as $value){
        echo $value;
        DB::ex('Delete from jobs where job_id='.$value);
        @shell_exec("rm -rf ".PRIVATE_DIR."jobs/".$value."/");        
    }
    header("Location: ".preg_replace("/\&delete\=[0-9]*/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    }
```

May I have some direction on this please...Im hoping I am on the right track.

Comment: Oh. Lovely. Directly using user-provided data in a `shell_exec()`? Enjoy having your server ENTIRELY destroyed. Why not use http://php.net/unlink? As for deleting from data, what database call? You have no DB code at all. Perhaps you should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28SQL%29

Comment: so that line would be: unlink(.PRIVATE_DIR."jobs/".$value."/" ); ? @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>&delete=' + jid;
```

you were missing a "php" on the start tag

Comment: Thank you for this - the issue is still around